# add space after each group of three numbers in java text area

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

i have a Text Area where input is just numbers, i want to group the text by three , means to  add space after each group of three numbers.
Any help how to achieve it ?

example :
if i want to input 123456
it will be automatically entered as"123 456 " the space automatically added after each third number.

I suppose this will be done in TextValueChanged(java.awt.event.TextEvent evt) Right ? But How ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question. It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post
code samples of what you have done.

Comment: @Matt thanks for advising . Is it good now after editing ?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your input numbers one-by-one and every third index draw a space.
Starting at 0 that would be a space at i = 2, 5, 8 ...

```
for(int i = 0; i < inputNumbers.length; i++;)
{
    if((i+1)/3 == 1) //this is just a janky condition i pulled out of my ear in a sec, you'll find a better one
    {
        //draw your number
        //draw a space
    }
}
```

Comment: Should probably use a regex pattern so validation can be done at the same time. Ie: 12A3509 should fail with a reason logged.  My regex-fu is rusty, but it'd be like "([0-9]{3})+" and you could just iterate through the groups and highlight the nonconforming parts.

Comment: @RandomCoder_01 something like this code?? :                                               `private void codeTextValueChanged(java.awt.event.TextEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here
     String var =code.getText();
     var = var.replace(/([0-9]{3})/g, "$1 ");
    }   `